# Gson crash at fromJson method

Tags: java, android, gson, json

I'm trying to convert a simple JSONObject into a string, but keep getting crashes.

```
classStr = (Class<T>) String.class;
Gson gson = new Gson();
dataObject = gson.fromJson( obj, classStr );
```

obj is --> `{ "myData" : "1234" }`.
** when obj is just a string( "myDate:1234" ) it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code is used to Convert Java or Json Object into GsonString:

```
//Here Object may b collection object or any other java object
public String convertToGsonString(Object obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(obj);
}
```

Convert gsonString into Object:

```
 public Object convertFromGson(String gsonString) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Object>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(gsonString, type);
}
```

for example, here considering Object as a HashMap:

```
public String convertToGsonString(HashMap<String,String> obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(obj);
}
```

convert from GsonStringTo HashMap:

```
public HashMap<String,String> convertFromGson(String gsonString) {

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,String>>() {
  }.getType();
  return gson.fromJson(gsonString, type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use HashMap <String, String> but with Class<T> instead of Type in fromJson method?

Comment: `Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); and then
   (Class<T>) map.getClass(); ` 
That's the solution I was looking for, but yours with 'type' is good too.

Answer (score 1):

**Make a Model class.**

```
Class DataObject {
public String myData;
}
```

Then use this code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
DataObject dataObject = gson.fromJson(obj, DataObject.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid creating a custom class just for that?
Can it be implemented via HashMap<String,String>? so dataObject would have Key (String)  = "myData" and Value (String)  = "1234" ?

Comment: Your Welcome. Yes you can, just extract String value from JSONObject and put it to HashMap with key myData. @BVtp

Comment: you mean call toString on the obj and then put it to HashMap? How would I separate the key and value?
I probably misunderstood you..
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

Gson gson = new Gson();

DataObject dataObject = gson.fromJson( obj, DataObject.class );

Because the signature of Gson fromJson method is :

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
```

Here it returns the object of class type T. So, instead of using String.class (mismatch class type) use the class of dataObject instance, else it will throw JsonSyntaxException.